# "The item already exists" when adding trying to add files to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am having problems adding files to TFS Online. Here are the steps I made to get up to this point:

1. Created a project in TFS "**SomeProject_Classic**"
2. Mapped it to a path in my computer `C:\SomeProject\classic`
3. Pushed all files from from WITHIN the `\classic` folder to this project
4. Deleted the project in TFS
5. Recreated a new project in TFS with the *same name* ("SomeProject_Classic")
6. Mapped it to a path on my computer `C:\SomeProject`
7. I try to add the `classic` folder (not only the files in it like step 3, but the entire folder itself)

On this last step, it gives me the error "**The item $/SomeProject_Classic/classic/somefile.txt already exists**".

Basically, I think it is having a problem thinking that I have already added these files because I created a project with the same name in TFS and never "checked those files out for deletion" before deleting the project.. I feel like I need to clear a cache or TFS memory or something. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was somewhat related to Cece's answer in that even though it was deleted on the server, my local computer still thought the file were in the uploaded workspace.

What I did was create a temp folder `TempRepo` on my desktop and moved the files from the "classic" folder to it. I mapped my workspace to this `TempRepo` folder. Then I was able to "add existing files" to the workspace and push my files from this temp folder to Visual Studio Online.

When I was done, I just mapped the workspace back to the original folder and performed a "Get" operation. Now I have all the files uploaded onto TFS and the correct workspace set.

Answer (score 7):

Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\６.0\Cache.

Use the tf destroy command to destroy, or permanently delete, version-controlled files from Team Foundation version control. Check:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the file name. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do "Undo Pending changes" and delete the files and check-in again...problem will be fixed..